# Shell Script Source: Not Found

Tags: bash, shell

I am running the following simple script to test the block of code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                         

# Load nvm and install latest production node                                                                                       
source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install v0.10.12
nvm use v0.10.12
```

If the file name is test.sh with the above code, I get the following error:

```
test.sh: 5: test.sh: source: not found
test.sh: 6: test.sh: nvm: not found
test.sh: 7: test.sh: nvm: not found
```

Based on my review in SO, it appears the error with the script is originating at ==> source: not found. When I type this at CLI myself the code works fine. For some reason I am not able to execute this code through a shell script.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: The line numbers in the error messages all seem to be off by 1. Does your file have DOS line endings?

Comment: I am executing the script on an Amazon Web Service Ubuntu instance. The line numbers are off by because I removed the printf statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) says Bash but the symptom suggests that you are running it with `sh`, which doesn't have a `source` command. Superficially, changing `source` to just a dot will fix that, but of course, if the sourced file contains any Bashisms, it will fail on those instead (perhaps more subtly, with incorrect results but no error message).

```
#!/bin/sh                                      
# Load nvm and install latest production node
. $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install v0.10.12
nvm use v0.10.12
```

Usually, it is better to mark the script as executable and have the OS select the correct interpreter through the shebang mechanism; then you don't have to remember whether the script file contains Bash commands or `sh` commands or Python code or compiled code or whatever, nor notice if this changes from one version to another.

So instead of

```
sh script
```

you'd do

```
chmod +x ./script # the first time
./script
```

Once the permissions are correct, only the second line is needed. There are some minor additional caveats, which is why some busy developers sometimes give the simplest possible instructions for the immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you tripleee for the answer. Your additional comments for making the script executable helped me solve the next few problems for integrating that script back into the main code. Having the OS select the correct interpreter through the shebang statement makes complete since.

Comment: Great answer, simply explained!

Answer (score 0):

> chmod +x $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
>
> then
>
> sh $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh or . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh

Comment: That will not source the script, so the `nvm` command will not have access to variables defined by `nvm.sh` (or possibly will not be defined at all).