# Shell script error in UNIX but works in CentOS - source: not found

Tags: shell, unix

myconf.sh

```
setting1=val1
setting2=val2
export setting1
export setting2
```

Then I call this conf file in my runner.sh, but I get the error "runner.sh: source: not found". Initially I was using source myconf.sh when calling it inside and saw in some posts that I should be using "." instead of "source".

myrunner.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. myconf.sh
echo "$setting1"
echo "$setting2"
```

I'm calling myrunner.sh through this command

```
sh myrunner.sh
```

Please let me know if I'm actually doing something wrong. I'm able to call it properly without errors in my CentOS image but when we execute it in a UNIX box I'm hitting the error.

Thanks!

Comment: What platform is this not working on?  What specific UNIX is this?

Comment: Are you saying that it's failing with `source: not found` even after you replaced `source` with `.`?

Comment: Using `.` is not wrong.  Using `source` is useful because human readers often find it more readable than `.`, but they are exactly equivalent. 
 However, it is problematic because not all shells recognize it.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes. It's failing even after I replaced source with . as I saw from this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506974/shell-script-source-not-found

Comment: `source` is wrong with `sh`. The POSIX standard only guarantees `. myconf.sh`, not `source myconf.sh`, to work, and if you're using `sh` (and not `bash`, `ksh`, etc) to run your scripts, the only functionality guaranteed to be present is that in the POSIX sh standard.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - looks like you hit the nail-on-the-head -- again. I suspect the error message and the OS are for that reason.

Comment: @user3694537 I'm partially guessing here, but did you perhaps mean "no, it no longer says `source: not found`. When I replaced it with `.`, the message changed to `.: myconf.sh: not found`"? If so, you really need to update your post to reflect this.

Comment: @thatotherguy - you're latest response just gave me some thought. I was browsing the screenshot provided to me by the operator who executed the script. Since it's the runner.sh that is being specified not found it seems like the runner.sh is being executed in the wrong directory. Let me double-check on this.

Answer (score 1):

What is your `$PATH` env var set to?

You may just need to include the current directory in your path or prefix the filename.

Example: `source ./myconf.sh`

ETA: As noted; putting the current directory `.` into your path may not be the most desirable thing. I suggested it simply to explain why your script may work on one system but not another.

Comment: Adding the current directory to `PATH` is not a good idea because you might one day this script in a directory with unknown contents, and something else might run as part of the `myconf.sh` invocation. Something like `source $(dirname $0)/myconf.sh` might be more reliable. But your are correct that if the target script is not in `PATH`, its path must be specified.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Agreed.

Comment: `. "$(dirname "$0")/myconf.sh"` would be less fault-prone than the above.

Comment: I've never included the current directory in my `PATH`, and yet `.`/`source` still works fine for me.

Comment: @jwodder, yes, that's a special case; `.`/`source` looks in the current directory additional to (actually, *prior* to) the PATH. But adding `.` to the `PATH` means you're vulnerable to that class of vulnerabilities with non-`source` invocations.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, POSIX **explicitly** does not specify searching the current directory, so shells implementing this are going beyond what the standard specifies; see the RATIONALE section in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html

Comment: @charlesDuffy yes in my actual script i'm already using the whole path